# exception on use of Html.Action when controller is decorated with outputcache attribure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, razor, outputcache

An exception is thrown when I call `Html.Action` from a view when the controller is decorated with the `OutputCache` attribute. But when I remove the attribute from the controller everything works as expected.

I do not want to remove the OutputCache-attribute and I don't understand how the attribute is responsible for throwing the exception. How do I solve this problem?

Controller:

```cs
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult Test()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("test");
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div>
    <!-- Tab 1 -->
    @Html.Action("Test")
</div>
```

Exception:

```
{"Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'."}
```

InnerException

```
{"Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions."}
```

**Update**
I only get the exception when I try to disable the outputcache. Either by adding the above attribute  or setting the duration to 0.

Comment: It could be that you're having an Exception and a `HandleError` filter (or something similar) is trying to redirect to a friendly error page. show the full stacktrace or look deeper for inner Exceptions

Comment: haim770, I cannot find anything.

Comment: haim770, you were correct, there was a custom error attribute that intercepted an exception on the Outputcache attribute. You cannot use that attribute without specifying a duration larger than 0. I am working on a solution and will post it here when I am ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outputcache attribute generated a hidden exception because the Duration property was not specified. However the duration cannot be 0 so that made the OutputCache attribute not very usefull for me. I decided to create my own NoCache attribute to take care of the work. (See code below)

Using this attribute instead of the OutputCacheAttribute solved my problem.

```cs
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Cormel.QIC.WebClient.Infrastructure
{
    public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case an `OutputCache` filter is applied with `Location=Server` (on your Controller for example), your new `NoCache` filter may not override it.

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to disable the cache too, go to 
`Global.asax.cs` file and add the following code,

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
```

Now you don't need to add the `[OutputCache]` attribute now. Let me know if it worked ! Cheers

Comment: This will help, I will create my own NoCache attribute with the help of these methods. I'll post it here when I'm ready.