# RedirectResult returns cached page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using RedirectResult to redirect the user to the home page after login. Every thing is working fine on IIS Express, but when deploying to IIS 7 I get a cached version of the home page when logging. When reloading the homepage, I get the correct version customized for the user.

I tried to decorate the login action with [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)] attribute but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Cache by adding the following code to your `Global.asax` file,

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't need to stop caching completely since I am using webfonts, I need to reload the page when loggin only.

Comment: Creating a CustomFilterAttribute might help you, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18761621/2121389